# library file is found by ldconfig but not by ldd

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library

I have built OpenGL acceleration libraries (libGL and libGLU) which I keep in a specific directory, `/usr/lib/mali`. I also have a software implementation of OpenGL which is installed in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`. Both directories are added to `/etc/ld.so.conf` with `/usr/lib/mali` coming first, so that the programs prefer libraries from it.

`ldconfig` finds all the libraries:

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v
/usr/lib/mali:
libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1
libGL.so.1.2.0 -> libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:
libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.5.08005
libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.08005
```

The weird part is that `ldconfig` creates a symlink `libGL.so.1.2.0`, but does nothing for `libGLU`. The `ldd` output is even weirder:

```
ldd `which glxgears`
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/mali/libGLU.so.1 (0xb6e4a000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGL.so.1 (0xb6bb5000)
libGL.so.1.2.0 => /usr/lib/mali/libGL.so.1.2.0 (0xb67f1000)
```

The output suggests that the `libGLU` is taken from the hardware-accelerated directory, while `libGL` sticks to the software implementation. `libGL.so.1.2.0` is also loaded for some reason. In the end, the software implementation is used when I run `glxgears`.

Can anyone explain me what's going on? What can I do to make my hardware-accelerated libraries load by default, without removing or overwriting the software libraries from `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` (they are in fact a package dependency)?

PS: the hardware-accelerated libraries do work when I add `/usr/lib/mali/` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed in my Makefile settings. Inspecting the library with `objdump` revealed the root cause:

```
$ objdump -p libGL.so.1 |grep SONAME
SONAME               libGL.so.1.2.0
```

`ldd` showed both `libGL.so.1` and `libGL.so.1.2.0`, because the first one was imported by `glxgears` and the second one was imported by my implementation of `libGLU` which was build against hardware-accelerated version of `libGL` and thus knew its soname, `libGL.so.1.2.0`.

The fix was to change the soname with `-soname,libGL.so.1`.